# How to un-nock an arrow

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Is there a way in Oblivion un-nock an arrow so that I do not have to fire it?

The [method used in Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35138/how-do-i-un-nock-an-arrow), which is to sheath your weapon, does not work for Oblivion.

Comment: I typically un-nock mine in the knee of an adventurer.

Comment: What things can you still do? Open the inventory, use hotkeys, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot. There is however a mod that you can use which allows you to do this if you are okay with using mods.

You can access the mod here:

http://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/9333/?

You will need the Oblivion Script Extender, which you can get here:

http://obse.silverlock.org

Answer (score 1):

*Confirmed working in Oblivion for PS3:*

If you talk to someone, completing dialog un-nocks the arrow. Obviously this may be overly difficult unless you accidentally nock the arrow in a town.